# bootstrap sliding panel from the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hie guys, i want to design a floating panel that works like the iPad/iPhone Control Center menu.i tried searching around but all i could find were simple in page collapsible panels.When collapsed, the panel should only show a small arrow/ button at the bottom of the screen that will expand the panel in an upward direction.Also the panel should be floating as demonstrated in the dashboard below.
A sample of what i want is demonstrated in the weather dashboard below.[Check out that panel floating from below in this dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c4dk.gif). [This is what i currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg3xF.png). The side panel is a plugin for the Leaflet.js api i am using

Comment: Hi can you please create fiddle for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `position: fixed` to keep the drawer at the bottom of the screen and visible, even on scroll.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxXowM for an example.